# Python googlesearch library __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'search'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# Code to search in google by the input we give using python googlesearch library
# missing 1 required positional argument search
# import modules in try block
try:
   from googlesearch import *
   from sys import stdout
   from time import sleep
except ImportError:
   print("Modules Not Found...!!!")
# user-agent
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0)'

class Gsearch_python:
   def __init__(self, hits, search):
        self.hits = hits
        self.search = search
    def Gsearch(self):
        Hits = hits(query=self.hits, lang='en', domains='com', user_agent=USER_AGENT)
        print("No.Of Hits: ", Hits)
        for letter in search(query=self.search, tld='com', lang='en', num=10, start=0, stop=100, pause=2.0, user_agent=USER_AGENT):
            sys.stdout.write(letter)
            time.sleep(.03)
            print(letter)
    # input the search query

Input = input("Enter your search query: ")

if __name__=='__main__':
     gs = Gsearch_python(Input)
     gs.Gsearch()
```

Comment: Well, you defined `__init__` as taking `(hits, search)` and then in main call it `Gsearch_python(Input)`. You're missing one argument.....

Comment: could you define it more please

Comment: in the class `Gsearch_python`, you have `def __init__(self, hits, search)` which means on creating a new object you need to pass two arguments: `hits, search`. Then in the main block you have `gs = Gsearch_python(Input)` so you're creating an object with one argument, hence the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You class `Gsearch_python` is expecting two arguments `hits` and `search`. In your `__main__` block you are calling the class with only one argument which is `Input`.

```
class Gsearch_python:
    # This class take two arguments hits and search
    def __init__(self, hits, search):
        self.hits = hits
        self.search = search
```

```
Input = input("Enter your search query: ")

if __name__=='__main__':
    # this call to the class takes one aguments. Input
    gs = Gsearch_python(Input)
    gs.Gsearch()
```

The error `Python googlesearch library __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'search'` clearly tells you that your call to the **init**() is missing a required argument. This means you need to either add an argument to `Gsearch_python(Input)` or you need to change the class so it only accepts one argument.

*A little bit extra:*

I think what you are trying to do. Is something like this, please look through the comments so you learn from your mistakes please do not just blindly copy the code.

- You import `from sys import stdout` but you use `sys.stdout.write(letter)` this will cause a NameError. Changed to use `import sys`.
- Likewise you use `from time import sleep` but you call `time.sleep`. Change to use `import time`
- Modified your `__init__` to take one argument `search`. `hits` is not a required argument.
- Default `self.hits` to equal `None` as initially it has no value.
- Changed `hits()` to use the `self.search` attribute as you are getting the numbers of hits for a search not hits.
- The result of `hits()` now gets assigned to `self.hits`.

```
# Code to search in google by the input we give using python googlesearch library
# missing 1 required positional argument search
# import modules in try block
try:
    from googlesearch import *
    import sys
    import time
except ImportError:
    print("Modules Not Found...!!!")
# user-agent
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0)'


class Gsearch_python:
    def __init__(self, search):
        self.search = search
        self.hits = None

    def Gsearch(self):
        self.hits = hits(query=self.search, lang='en', domains='com',
                    user_agent=USER_AGENT)
        print("No.Of Hits: ", self.hits)
        for letter in search(query=self.search, tld='com', lang='en', num=10,
                             start=0, stop=100, pause=2.0,
                             user_agent=USER_AGENT):
            sys.stdout.write(letter)
            time.sleep(.03)
            print(letter)
    # input the search query


Input = input("Enter your search query: ")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gs = Gsearch_python(Input)
    gs.Gsearch()
```

Hope this helps, keep coding, keep reading, keep trying.

Comment: @NitheeshPaul if it helps you resolve your issue please upvote and accept the answer.